# SSIS - File System task cannot find file path after using script task to assign variable

Tags: c#, excel, file, ssis, ssis-2012

In my current project I have to take an excel file of known directory but unknown name, put it into a database table and then move and rename the excel file used.

As this is my first project I've used a few tutorials and stackoverflow pages a long the way, hence why control flow is all inside a for each loop (even if it might not be needed), but here is the control flow:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nepgg.png

Here is my Script task to find the excel file and assign the variables:

```
  public void Main()
  {
        string directoryLocation = @"I:\All\L3VA Import\"; //Change this for new directory
        int directoryLength = directoryLocation.Length;

        string[] filePath = Directory.GetFiles(directoryLocation, "*.xls*");

        int filePathLength = filePath[0].Length;

        Dts.Variables["myConnectionString"].Value = filePath[0];
        Dts.Variables["myFileName"].Value = filePath[0].Substring(directoryLength, filePathLength - directoryLength);
```

I then use a Data Flow task to pump the spreadsheet data into OLE DB, which doesn't work on its own, but works if the Script Task is executed first, making me believe it is correctly assigning my variables.

My issue comes when I then try to move and rename this file using a File System Task, which seems not to find the value of these variables and encounters an error:

> Error: 0xC002F304 at File System Task, File System Task: An error occurred with >the following error message: "Could not find a part of the path.".
>
> Task failed: File System Task

Here is the variable list used and file system task:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6FWD.png

Comment: Sorry, why the activities are parallel and not sequential?  Should not you first run the import and then move the file? Try to set the variable myConnectionString with the whole path and not just the filename in the File System Task; the source and destination variables in the File System Task should contain  path + filename

Comment: If you look at the code
        string[] filePath = Directory.GetFiles(directoryLocation, "*.xls*"); 
        Dts.Variables["myConnectionString"].Value = filePath[0];
myConnectionString is the whole file path.  I added an extra green arrow in the hope that it would keep the value of myConnectionString to the file system task, which doesn't seem to be happening

Comment: ...it all seems ok , better check the destination variable , if the path is correct and so on...

Comment: Sorry if I ask , we have to verify all cases...looking at the variables, the folder QELIZ already exists?

Comment: Just came back to say checking it today I saw that the System::UserName variable had the QELIZ\\ section which was causing the confusion as well! Thanks for help, realised when I used the "Watch" debug window. All working now.

Comment: why not use a foreach container on the directory.  no need for script and you can loop through all of the files.  Also there should be no precedence directly from your script task to your file task it should only come off your data flow task.  Note I love scripts just not for tasks that don't need them....

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that how will you decide which Excel File is most appropriate if more than 1 file exists.  Will you need to loop through multiple of them?  Anyway, if you use a `Foreach Loop Container` and set it up to search the directory just like your script does you wont need the script task.  So you could do as follows:

- Setup a variable to hold the file path
- Add `Foreach Loop Container` and Configure to search directory and map variable to what you just setup
- Add your `data flow`
- After you setup your `data flow` on a static `Excel Connection` setup a `expression` on the `Connection Manager` to use the `File Path Variable` as the `connection string`
- Add your file system task and set the source path as a variable

Note because you likely will need to build your destination path dynamically you would probably want a few more variables to accomplish the task in an easier manner.

1. FilePath - but hold only file name and extension from `foreeach loop`
2. FullFilePath - dynamic variable that uses an expression to combine that FilePath to the directory being searched, this would get used in Excel Connection manger and as source on the file system task.
3. DestinationFullFilePath - this would be an expression that combines FilePath with the destination directory, this would get used as the destination on the file system task.